# Website allows horizontal scroll for some reason

Tags: html, css, 960.gs

On my site: http://rocketroofing.us/rocket there is a bunch of horizontal scroll. I can't figure out what's causing this. I don't want there to be any horizontal scroll. The template i bought uses the 960 grid system so that's why i'm so thrown off on what's causing this issue.

Comment: Perhaps you should speak to whoever you bought the template from.

Comment: Which browsers are you seeing this in? Looks good in Chrome.

Comment: I'm seeing it on Firefox on a macbook. If i 2 finger scroll sideways a little bit it happens. I can't get it to happen on my Windows 7 machine with shift mousewheel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding `overflow-x:hidden;` to `body` in your stylesheet.

Answer (score 0):

Are you referring to the slide show effect?  I see in the source code there is a div called "slideshow" on line 113, and "slider" on 114.  The slides seem to be timed.  Is there something on the CSS page, or a Javascript piece of code that's driving this?

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't see any horizontal scroll bars in your site? Which browser and which resolution are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Replace this with what you have in CSS file:

```
.style3#header ul.menu {
    /*background:url('../php-includes/rgba.php?name=black&a=60'); */ 
    background-color:rgba(0,0,0,0.6);
    -webkit-border-radius:4px;
    -moz-border-radius:4px;
    border-radius:4px;
    padding:0 20px;
    margin: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

it usually happens by setting CSS text-indent property to value like -99999 in Safari and Firefox.